# I am getting barplot , but not getting scatterplot

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, scatter-plot

I am on python 2.7, with spyder IDE and this is my data:

```
          Duration      ptno
           7432.0  X35133502100
           7432.0  X35133502100
          35255.0   T7956000304
          35255.0   T7956000304
          17502.0   T7956000304
          17502.0   T7956000304
             46.0   T7956000304
             46.0   T7956000304
```

The code:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.read_csv('Nissin_11.09.2018.csv')

bx = df1.plot.bar(x='ptno', y='d', rot=0)

plt.setp(bx.get_xticklabels(),rotation=30,horizontalalignment='right')

plt.show()
```

I get a nice bar plot as I wanted for each value mentioned in columns `Duration`   &   `ptno`. For reference I am attaching image file of the plot.

[image: Bar plot of the dataframe]

But when I try to get a `scatter` plot with:

```
df1.plot.scatter(x='ptno', y='d')
```

It throws a error as :

`ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric`

How can I have a 'scatter' plot for my data ??

As suggested by @Hristo Iliev I used his code:

```
import seaborn as sns
_ = sns.stripplot(x='ptno', y='d', data=df1)
```

[image: It only plot two unique values on axis]

But It only plot two unique values on axis where I would like to have all values on x axis as my bar plot has x axis values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use pure matplotlib. You need to create an array of numbers to use as the x axis, i.e. `[1,2,3,4,5,...]` and then change the tick labels to the value of the column `ptno`.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Duration":[7432,7432,35255,35255,17502,17502,46,46],
                    "ptno":["X35", "X35", "T79", "T79", "T79", "T79", "T79", "T79"]})

dummy_x = np.arange(len(df1.ptno))

plt.scatter(dummy_x, df1.Duration)
plt.xticks(dummy_x, df1.ptno)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make scatter plots with non-numeric values as indicated by the error. In a scatter plot, the position of each point is determined by the location on the real axis of the value of each variable. Categorical or string values such as `T7956000304` have no direct mapping to a position on the real axis.

What you can plot though is a series of strip plots, one for each unique value of `ptno`. That's easiest to do with Seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
_ = sns.stripplot(x='ptno', y='d', data=df1)
```

Comment: Your solution is just creating two unique values on x axis and plotting on it. I need each value from column in x axis as I have posted in the bar plot. I have updated my question with your solution. Kindly have a look on it :)

Comment: @suryarahul, it was not apparent from your initial question that you want repeated instances with the *same* values of `ptno` to appear at *different* positions along the X axis. This is not how regular scatter plots look like. In your case, a simple mapping like the one suggested by DavidG should do the trick.